# Create and deploy app on Heroku from Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a Node web app that can take commands from users. One command allows the user to do the following:

1. Create Heroku app
2. Deploy the app using the code from GitHub

Manually, I can deploy the app using command like "heroku create" and "git push heroku master".  I would like to do these steps automatically from a Node app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Node's Heroku client library:

- https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client